# jQuery hover interrupting toggleClass

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

so below is my script. I intend to do something really basic i.e. have different background-color on hover on different buttons (regular/inactive and active). And when clicked, toggle between the two states.

Now, this code does the hover correctly but doesn't toggles.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".button").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#E4E4E4");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#EDEDED");
        }
    );
    $(".active").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#F5F9FF");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#EBF3FF");
        }
    );
    $(".button").click(function() {
        alert("The button is clicked!");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

And, this code does toggles but I have to disable hover for it to happen

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*
    $(".button").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#E4E4E4");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#EDEDED");
        }
    );
    $(".active").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#F5F9FF");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#EBF3FF");
        }
    );*/
    $(".button").click(function() {
        alert("The button is clicked!");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

TL;DR I am not able to use `hover()` and `toggleClass()` together. 
Note: The alert shows though.

Comment: Without a snippet, can't confirm if this is the issue, but: https://api.jquery.com/hover/  "*"Bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer **enters** and **leaves** the elements*" - if you add `active` while over the button, you won't get the hover-in event

Comment: The issue is that `$(".class").event` will only apply to elements that exist at the time the code is called.  When you run your `$(".active")` there are no .active elements at the time, so the hover doesn't get assigned.

Comment: Does this do what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/bnp756eu/

Comment: Same issue applies - for the ones that are .active when you call `$(".active").hover` gets the event and *keeps the event* even when you remove the .active.   Your code does not say "apply hover to [all] active elements" it says "get the [current] active elements and apply hover to them"

Comment: Can you redescribe the problem?  What does it do that you don't want? What doesn't it do?  The hover won't work on newly toggled items as described above.  The toggleClass works fine as shown here (where toggling the class changes the font) https://jsfiddle.net/u8s2wbzL/  *toggling the class will not get the "other" hover effect to work*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I join the comment above about the event you are trying to generate on an element which does not exist in the DOM at the time.

You can style your elements with css and then trigger the class on click with javascript.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
button {
    background-color: blue;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: royalblue;
}

button.active {
    background-color: purple;
}

button.active:hover {
    background-color: rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">
  Click Me
</button>
<button class="button active">
  Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: Agreed, that's where I was going: https://jsfiddle.net/keyn1dow/  If you add the jsfiddle code into a snippet in your answer you'll get an upvote from me - it answers the requirement of the question, but OP doesn't seem to believe the actual issue.

Comment: Made a few tweaks to the answer - made it a statement instead of a question and added OPs "by default active buttons"

Comment: but that still doesn't explain what the problem in my code was.

Comment: Well, I explained that earlier :)  but don't worry about it and use css `:hover`

Comment: What? I still don't understand why $(this).toggleClass("active"); doesn't work when hover code is there, but works when hover code is commented out. Shouldn't it be independent of hover?

Comment: The first AND the second events are working (there ARE some active buttons from the start). THE THIRD EVENT is not working ie. the toggleClass one.

Comment: see you can do both the hovers properly

Comment: you just can't change from inactive to active or vice-versa

Comment: The active class toggle work well (See in the chrome devtools). Problem was: your buttons are not styled. So the active one have no background color. Fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/ehzx1rfa/1/